# Split() method and commas and not white space bet

Tags: java

I use the split method using the comma as my delimiter but the problem is that there is a white spacing between the comma and it is taken as a token for example:

`String animal= new String("cat,dog,cat fish,tiger");`

```
animal.split(",");
```

the output will be like this:

- cat
- dog
- cat
- fish
- tiger

but I want it to be like this:

- cat
- dog
- cat fish
- tiger

Comment: Why would you think the output is the first list?

Comment: "impossible is nothing" ;)

Comment: Voted to close, unfortunately there is no category "Poster tells BS", which would be appropriate here.

Comment: Cats and Fish may not be on one line, because otherwise the cat would eat the fish, that's why.

Comment: Sorry I didn't post in the whole code I figure it out the problem already. Sorry about all the trouble please delete my post.

Answer (score 1):

I"m not able to reproduce your problem.  I think your code must have something else going on that you're not including in your question.

My code:

```
class Foo {
  public static void main(String args[])  {
    String animal = "cat,dog,cat fish,tiger";
    String[] animals = animal.split(",");
    System.out.println(animals[2]);
  }
}
```

Output is "cat fish", as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an error in your program, cause if I run the following:

```
    String animal= new String("cat,dog,cat fish,tiger");

    String[] split = animal.split(",");

    for (String s : split) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

This is produced:

- cat
- dog
- cat fish
- tiger

So it seems okay.